# "Looking to + infinitive" vs "Looking to + gerund"

Tags: differences, infinitives, gerunds, bare-infinitive

Which is the correct expression, *looking to build* or *looking to building*?

> Whether you are looking to build. . . .

or

> Whether you are looking to build**ing**. . . .

Comment: Related and possible duplicate of [43 questions tagged with both *infinitive* and *gerund*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/infinitive+gerund), notably including http://english.stackexchange.com/q/329 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/63476 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/38964 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/25075 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/18772 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/23537 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/88014 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/13334 http://english.stackexchange.com/q/115073 and many more besides.

Comment: [General Reference](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=looking+to+build%2Clooking+to+building&year_start=1958&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=) says that “looking to building” does not occur.

Comment: @tchrist: Google Books says that [looking to going](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22looking+to+going%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) *does* occur. Admittedly, only 184 times, compared to tens of thousands of [looking to **go**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22looking+to+go%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but closely-related forms such as [They look to going to a different place every year](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22look+to+going+to+a+different%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) don't seem completely unreasonable to me.

Answer (score 3):

The grammatical choice would be:

> “Whether you are looking to build…”

i.e. the infinitive.

Comment: The present participle [does occur in such contexts](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22%22looking+to+buying%22%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but it's not common, and I would say it's dialectal and/or uneducated.

Comment: "Looking to build something" but "looking into building something", and the meaning of "looking" has changed too. It's a miracle that some people actually learn this language.